# import javax.persistence.EntityManager error

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I have copied my project from pc to other and i got error

1. import javax.persistence.EntityManager; 
   importjavax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; import
   javax.persistence.Persistence; import javax.persistence.Query;

the compiler doesn't know them, in the lib folder i added 3 jar from the local pc
derby.jar eclipselink.jar and also javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112161009.jar

what could be the reason

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to refresh the project and then do a clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add two more Jar's that are

```
toplink-essentials.jar
toplink-essentials-agent.jar
```

Add this external jars to your project

Comment: you can download it from
http://download.java.net/maven/1/toplink.essentials/jars/

Comment: thanks i dont have error now but when i run the model i got the follwoing error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-30004] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0 (Build 35 (02/16/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: /poc.mock.service/bin/
Internal Exception: 
(1. cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.)

Answer (score 0):

at first refresh your project, if you copied with OS.

then maybo you have to add them to your build path.

1 <kbd>right click</kbd> on your project -> <kbd>build path</kbd> -> <kbd>configure build path</kbd> -> <kbd>libraries</kbd> -> <kbd>add JARs...</kbd>

2 select project/lib folder and choose the jars to add them.

3 click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: Thanks But I already do that for this jar without successes ,any other thing ?

Comment: i think this classes are not in the jars, so you need to download appropriate jars

Comment: btw how i add it to the lib?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add those jar on **classpath**. If you are running the project in eclipse, simply select project properties=>build path=>add jar